# CCA attack on RSA padded with random oracle

Tags: rsa, padding, chosen-ciphertext-attack

I'm trying to do the ex 11.15 of the Katz-Lindell book.

Consider the RSA-based encryption scheme
in which a user encrypts a message $m ∈ $ {$0, 1$}$^l$ with respect to the public key $(N, e)$ by computing $m' := H(m)||m$ and outputting the ciphertext $c' := m'^e modN $. $(H : $ {$0, 1$}$^l → ${$0, 1$}$^n$ and assume $l + n < ||N||$, $||N||$ is the bit-length of N). The receiver
recovers $m'$ in the usual way and verifies that it has the correct form before outputting
the $l$ least-significant bits as $m$. Prove or disprove that this scheme is CCA-secure if $H$ is modeled as a random oracle.

I know that this scheme isn't CCA-secure because it's deterministic.

But I tried to transform the cyphertext without success, because if I modify the second part of $m'$ let's say computing $m''$, using another cyphertext and multiplying it to $c'$, then I need $H(m'')$ to compose a correct cyphertext but since I don't know $m'$ I'm not able to query $H(m'')$.

Comment: An attack against CPA security is an attack against CCA security which just chooses not to take advantage of the decryption oracle.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how could it be attacked with CPA attack?

Comment: You already observed that the scheme is deterministic. What does that tell you?

Comment: So I can just ask for the encryption of the messages (m0,m1) in the CPA-security game?

Comment: There's no need to ask. You can just compute it yourself.

Comment: @Processss Once you have found the answer, [please don't hesitate to answer your question yourself](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).